# DELETE FROM AllTables Where ColumnName="Some Text"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm working with some databases and I have quite a few items I need to remove from them. There are about 300 or so tables in each database and I am trying to find a way to drop the rows that contain the string I need to remove.

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName='Some String'
```

Works just fine, but I do not want to run that for each table. I'm hoping there is a way to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM * WHERE ColumnName='Some String'
```

I have been searching around on Google and have come accross several articles on how to drop all of the data in all the tables, which is not what I am trying to accomplish.

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

I am still somewhat new to SQL and I don't know if there is already a way to this and I am just not using the write search terms to find it.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Luckily that can't be done.

Comment: I think we can do it using dynamic query. Is the column name same for every object ??

Comment: Have a look at INFORMATION_SCHMEMA.TABLES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for other databases, too - on other databases, you only have to change the syntax for the concatenation from `+` to `||` and change schema and name of the `COLUMNS` system view / table.

Run the query to a report on file. Remove any headers/footers. Then, run that file as a SQL script.

```
SELECT
  'DELETE FROM ' + table_catalog
           + '.' + table_schema
           + '.' + table_name
  + ' WHERE ' + column_name
  + ' = ''Some String'';' 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE UPPER(column_name) = 'NAME'
;
```

My database, which happens to be Vertica, returns:

```
DELETE FROM gpb.agreement_type WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM gpb.product WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM gpb.account_type WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM gpb.document_type WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM gpb.transaction_type WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM gpb.account WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM public.people_with_dupes WHERE name = 'Some String';
DELETE FROM public.people WHERE name = 'Some String';
```

Comment: This seems to work, or at least the output says it has executed successfully and shows the same output as what you are showing. However when I query a table to see if its gone it is still there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Then you have the output of my query. But you have not executed that output yet. Either you copy-paste that output into your SQL input prompt, or you execute that file as an SQL script. I take it that you haven't done that.

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to this, I'll save it as an SQL script and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete column from single table :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Delete column from multiple table :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL += 'Alter table ' + Quotename(table_catalog)
           + '.' + Quotename(table_schema) + '.'
           + Quotename(TABLE_NAME) + '  DROP column '
           + Quotename(column_name) + ';'
FROM   information_schema.columns where COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name' -- 

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This returns 'Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL". Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7 Must declare the the scalar variable "@SQL".'

Comment: I updated post.specify your column name in 'your_column_name'

Comment: Don't try this if you want to delete `rows` only from the tables with satisfied condition  because it will drop the column itself. (if the above query will generate right syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented (but not [unknown](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)) stored procedure called `sp_MSforeachtable`.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ? WHERE ColumnName = 'Some String';
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:** You can use this technique to get rid from the tedious job of typing code for every table. You can first retrieve all the `objects` which have that `<column_name>` and then create a `loop` with `delete` statement. Please change `<column_name>` with your `real column name`.

Please try it, I am sure it will work for you:

```
select id = identity(int, 1, 1), o.name INTO #object_name 
from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
where type = 'u' and c.name = <column_name>

declare @i int = 1, @j int = 0, @sql varchar(500)
select @j = count(*) from #object_name
while (@i <= @j)
begin
    declare @tbl_name varchar(100)
    select @tbl_name = name from #object_name where id = @i
    set @sql = 'delete from ' + @tbl_name + ' where <column_name> = <some_string>'

    --print(@sql)
    exec(@sql)
    set @i = @i+1
end
```